# Quine - two dogmas of empiricism

Tags: empiricism, quine, analytic-synthetic-divide

I'm trying to understand this paper. Seems to me like it all stems from a rejection of "meaning"... ie: Quine is saying statements don't mean anything. And this is what leads to the rejection of the analytic-synthetic distinction. But if meanings do exist, then there's a simple distinction between analytic and synthetic... analytic statements are true in virtue of the meanings of the words... Synthetic statements are not.

So if we don't agree with Quine's rejection of meaning, then we can't accept the rest of the paper. Is that right?

Here's a link to the paper:

http://www.ditext.com/quine/quine.html

Comment: I have not read the paper (a link would be nice), however from what you stated, I would suggest the following.   Meaning is something that we choose to assign to words, symbols and statements.  Without that assignment, they are just those things with no meaning.  I do not believe it's intent is to self-propagate rejection, however if that is the meaning you give, then that is what it is. If you subtract 'meaning' and look at the letters and statements on the paper for what they are, you will find that communication breaks down, and you will also understand why there is no meaning.

Comment: @SanuelJackson, I've included a link.

Comment: @SanuelJackson, I agree with you. Which is why the paper confuses me.

Comment: Reading it now.

Comment: The problem is not that "meanings do not exist", but that they are too vague, there is no way to tell say if too terms are synonymous "by way of meanings" or due to empirical coincidence (he uses "bachelor" and "unmarried" as example). So to explain "analytic-synthetic distinction" one has to explain synonymy first, but synonymy means exactly that  coincidence of meanings of the terms is an analytic claim, and the whole enterprise is hopelessly circular. Disagreeing with Quine is not enough, one needs a non-circular proposal for synonymy/analyticity, and so far no one could offer one.

Comment: "are synonymous "by way of meanings" or due to empirical coincidence" I don't see the problem here. It's obvious with regards to the context of word use. If I say "all bachelors are unmarried"... this is obviously true in virtue of meanings, because bachelor refers to the same meaning as unmarried man. It has nothing to do with empirical coincidence.

Comment: I don't get why two labels refer to the same meaning isn't sufficient for synonymy. I mean this is perfectly unproblematic in daily life. Nobody actually thinks "all bachelors are unmarried men" could be an empirical matter do they?

Comment: "Obviously true" doesn't cut it. We may specify synonymous terms in a specific language by a table say, Quine has no problem with such "distinction", but it is of no use. What he asks for is definition of analyticity as such, i.e. definition that works for *arbitrary* language, and does not rely on circular recourse to synonymy, etc. "Nobody actually thinks different" may work like a table for familiar languages, but it tells us nothing as to what analyticity-in-a-language (with language as a *variable*) is. Analyticity, "meanings" and synonymy continue to run in a circle.

Comment: @Conifold, One can only judge analyticity after becoming familiar with a language. Within my own mind with regards to English, the words 'car' and 'automobile' have come to refer to the same meaning. This has happened after some familiarity and use of the language over years. So they are synonymous (by definition that they refer to the same meanings) at least in my own mind. Is this unproblematic or is there already circularity here?

Comment: I think that's Quine's point, one learns to judge synonymy or analyticity in familiar languages just like one learns to recognize flowers or animals, but if we want a theory of analyticity (flowers, animals) then saying that we will know it when we see it isn't much help. Positivists, against whom Two Dogmas were written, talked of analyticity not in natural languages but in arbitrary formal languages that can potentially be used in science, and relied on the distinction to separate "empirical" from "theoretical". Quine showed that they literally could not explain what they were talking about.

Comment: If there are only two types of knowledge analytic versus synthetic and it is difficult to specify the selection criteria for analytic then we can specify the selection criteria for synthetic making the analytic versus synthetic distinction more easily. If synthetic knowledge requires sense data from the sense organs to verify that it is true then analytic knowledge is any expression of language that is verified as true without needing any sense data from the sense organs. This way we can make the analytic versus synthetic distinction  without have to define what "semantic meaning" is.

Answer (score 6):

He is not rejecting *meaning*; what he says is:

> My present suggestion is that it is nonsense, and the root of much nonsense, to speak of a linguistic component and a factual component in the truth of any individual statement. Taken collectively, science has its double dependence upon language and experience; but this duality is not significantly traceable into the statements of science taken one by one.

Thus, **if** we deny that:

> the truth of a statement is somehow analyzable into a linguistic component and a factual component.

we have to reject the possibility of identifying a class of statements whose truth relies only on the "linguistic component", i.e. the class of *analytic* statements.

Comment: Ok. Then I'm missing something basic. Why can't I say, "a bachelor is an unmarried man." is an analytic statement because 'bachelor' means the same thing as 'unmarried man'. By virtue of meanings the statement is analytic. Why would Quine have a problem with this? Quine talks about how they come to mean the same thing... but I think this is irrelevant... somehow the two labels come to refer to the same meaning, and it is by virtue of this that we get that  "a bachelor is an unmarried man." is analytic. That's to me the common-sensical view when one has meanings.

Comment: @AmeetSharma - see [The Analytic/Synthetic Distinction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/#ProDis): the issue is clearly not conclusively settled... as usual in philosophy.

Comment: It is not a linguistic component and a factual component so much as it is a purely semantic component expressed using language and a component expressed using language that cannot be verified as true without sense data from the sense organs. If it can be verified as true without sense data from the sense organs then it is analytic.

Comment: @polcott The kind of epistemological foundationalism you are suggesting there is philosophically dead since the 1960s at the latest. It had been killed by Quine, Sellars, Davidson, and Putnam, so repeatedly and in different ways. Semantic expressions are more than mere correlates to physical states. Also, the comment misses the point of the answer, which correctly states Quine's reasoning. Since the question is about Quine, your discussions are moot and misplaced here.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking You are probably correct that my answer does not focus on directly what Quine is saying. I have found that it is sometimes enormously more effective to find the simplest possible reasoning the refutes the conclusion than it is to go tit-for-tat, point-by-point through overly convoluted reasoning. Quine is basically concluding that there is no sharp line of demarcation between analytic and synthetic sufficient to determine that analytic separately exists. By simply drawing this line sharply such that the result matches conventional understandings Quine is refuted,

Comment: on polcott's line of thinking, I look at certain statements like "Bachelor's are unmarried". "2+1=3". "Triangles have 3 sides". Then I have other statements like, "The sun rises in the east". "Jack opened the door". "I have a headache". Does Quine agree that human beings, for whatever reason do group the first 3 statements as having something in common and the last 3 as having something in common. As simply a question on human behavior, can we agree that humans do generally form this distinction?

Comment: @AmeetSharma Those examples are quite good.  Here is a related post that I wrote:   https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72059/does-this-augmentation-to-the-analytic-synthetic-distinction-overcome-quines

Answer (score 4):

Quine doesn't hold that statements don't mean anything (that indeed would be quite an extreme form of skepticism), but rather that the meaningfulness of statements should be considered not in isolation but only as a part of a broader theory or language. This is of course of Quine's holism. You can read more [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/#AnaSynDisArgAgaLogEmp).

Answer (score 1):

Quine is a complete empiricist, unlike rationalist such as Leibniz, Kant, Chomsky, here in *Two Dogmas* essentially he claims there are no "analytic" truths, but all truths involve an empirical aspect. Any possible meaning eventually comes from some sensory experience. If we haven't lived this life so far, how can we know *bachelor* is just a synonymy of *unmarried*? Accepting analyticity for Quine really means accepting rationalism which instead accepts meaning can be acquired from reason alone, no need for any experience. Even for the normal analytic tautology such as x=x is synthetic for Quine, since if you don't have some life experience how can you be sure a thing always equals itself even at a same time instant? How can you even know what equality (=) means without any sensory experience? How can you even know what simultaneity means without sense experience? (remember Special Relativity hinted most people didn't really understand the subtle motion-dependent relative nature of simultaneity)

So Quine want to discard the two unempirical dogmas left in logical empiricism to favor his more thorough pragmatism:

> Carnap, Lewis, and others take a pragmatic stand on the question of choosing between language forms, scientific frameworks; but their pragmatism leaves off at the imagined boundary between the analytic and the synthetic. In repudiating such a boundary I espouse a more thorough pragmatism. Each man is given a scientific heritage plus a continuing barrage of sensory stimulation; and the considerations which guide him in warping his scientific heritage to fit his continuing sensory promptings are, where rational, pragmatic.

Of course, later Saul Kripke proposed his famous rigid designators to try to preserve some analyticity (rationality)...

Comment: That would be consistent, but Quine has no problem with the proposition, "No unmarried man is married." ie: he's ok with logical modifiers. Only when using synonyms does he have an issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Dogmas_of_Empiricism Personally, I don't get this exception he makes, because without life experience how are you going to know "un" means negation etc.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Sounds a good thoughtful question... Here the degree is much different: for "un" has a logical negation meaning one doesn't need much experience, a new born baby probably can know happy and unhappy once a toy is thrown from her hand. But to know "bachelor" and "unmarried" one needs way more experience... So they only differ in degree,  not in kind, you're still not completely lost...

Answer (score 0):

Quine is only criticizing the current definition of of analytic versus synthetic distinction not that no such distinction can ever be made.

I am sure that he would realize that the sentence written on paper: "Quine had a Boston cream pie smashed into his face" is not identical to the first hand direct experience of {Quine had a Boston cream pie smashed into his face}. The difference between these words on paper and the actual physical event proves that there is some distinction between analytic and synthetic.

We might divide this distinction this way: whatever aspect of meaning that can be expressed using words is its analytic component and whatever aspect of meaning that cannot be expressed using words and can only be directly experienced as first hand physical sensations from the sense organs is its synthetic component.

Unanswered: Are there any sentences that are impossibly false?
**This sentence is comprised of words.**

Comment: Carnap once thought similarly about empirical  truths, he believed something like any empirical truth has a semantic scientific substantial part, and a remaining syntactic mathematical formal part. But later Godel incompleteness theorems strongly refuted this philosophy as math has its own semantic content, ie, model theory, not just proof theory believed by many before...

Comment: Because it is possible that five minutes ago never existed all empirical knowledge could possibly be false: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_hypothesis#Five-minute_hypothesis "This sentence is comprised of words." is the only kind of knowledge (analytical) that is perfectly certain.